# How do I select an item in a dropdown list where I have to scroll?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

On the following website: https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml?lang=en

I am trying to select the following dropdown list option via selenium:
Under `Headline category and Document Type`, on the first dropdown list I select `Headline Category`, then on the second list I want to select `Announcements and Notices -> New Listings (Listed Issuers/New Applicants -> Allotment Results`.

I have realised you have to use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector()` as none of the items on the list have unique ID's.
I have also realized you have to scroll the page when the option is not in view so that CSS selector can pick it up.

What I have SHOULD work but it doesn't? Can someone help me resolve this, please?

````
```python

# Select dropdown list
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#rbAfter2006 > div > div > div').click()
# Select Announcements and Notices
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#rbAfter2006 > div ~ div > div > div > div > ul > li ~ li ').click()

# Scroll down so that New Listings (Listed Issuers/New Applicants) is in view
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#rbAfter2006 > div ~ div > div > div > div > ul > li ~ li > a '
                                    '~ div > div > ul > li ~ li ~ li ~ li ~ li ~ li ~ li  ~ li ~ li')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

# Click New Listings (Listed Issuers/New Applicants)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#rbAfter2006 > div ~ div > div > div > div > ul > li ~ li > a '
                                    '~ div > div > ul > li ~ li ~ li ~ li ~ li ~ li ~ li ').click()


# THIS IS WHAT FAILS, Can't find element? I am currently printing the box so I know what is selected
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#rbAfter2006 > div ~ div > div > div > div > ul > li ~ li > a '
                                    '~ div > div > ul > li ~ li ~ li ~ li ~ li ~ li ~ li > a ~ div > ul > li ~ li').text)

```
````

I currently get an element not found an error

Comment: I've found, within the final css selector I am doing, it fails at at the last "div > ul". This "ul" is the one that cannot be found, when I'm clearly looking at it in the HTML of the website. It literally exists under the div so I am completely lost

Answer (score 0):

Can you try getting a list out of dropdown values probably using css selector like

> ul li a

then loop through to find a matching value and click it

Comment: The thing is I can't even loop through it. I cant find the dropdown list that appears when I click "New Listings (Listed Issuers/New Applicants) in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Ideally we should not select an element with such complex css selector, try to shorten the css selector.

Then,

Try to mouse hover to the first element in the drop down as,

```
driver.action.move_to(first_element_in_dropdown).perform
```

Then,

Try to scroll to the element which you need using,

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'nearest'});",element_to_be_selected)
```

Note: The code is in Ruby, try translating to python and use. This may help

Comment: Regarding the complex css selector - no element on the page has an ID / name apart from the actual bar of which the dropdown list is complained. Therefore the only way to select elements within that bar is to find them with a complex CSS selector right?

Comment: If you have any class aligned to the tags, you can use that to reduce the size of the css. like `div.class li.class`

Answer (score 0):

To click item from drop-down list induce `WebDriverWait` and `presence_of_element_located()` then use `location_once_scrolled_into_view` and click on the element using following xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml?lang=en')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,40)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.combobox-input-wrap a[data-value="rbAll"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="droplist-item"]/a[contains(.,"Headline Category")]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="rbAfter2006"]//div[@class="combobox-input-wrap"]/a[contains(.,"ALL")]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="droplist-group"]//ul[@class="droplist-items"]//li/a[contains(.,"Announcements and Notices")]'))).click()
ele=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="droplist-group droplist-submenu level2"]//ul//li/a[contains(.,"New Listings (Listed Issuers/New Applicants)")]')))
ele.location_once_scrolled_into_view
ele.click()
ele2=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="droplist-group droplist-submenu level3"]//ul//li/a[contains(.,"Allotment Results")]')))
ele2.location_once_scrolled_into_view
ele2.click()
```

**Browser Snapshot**

[image]